# Slice a dataframe with a hierarchy index

Tags: python, indexing, dataframe, slice, hierarchy

I have two dataframes. One has stock transactions (things like buy date, buy price, sell date, sell price).  The other dataframe has all the prices in date order with an hierarchy index of `['symbol', 'date']` indexing `'close'` price called `dfPrice`.

Not knowing a better way of submitting a dataframe to this group, I have made a record of the first 10 lines by:

```
ra = dfPrice.to_records()
```

yielding an `ra` of:

```
rec.array([('A', Timestamp('2000-09-01 00:00:00'), 39.84),
 ('A', Timestamp('2000-09-05 00:00:00'), 39.8),
 ('A', Timestamp('2000-09-06 00:00:00'), 38.63),
 ('A', Timestamp('2000-09-07 00:00:00'), 39.84),
 ('A', Timestamp('2000-09-08 00:00:00'), 38.15),
 ('A', Timestamp('2000-09-11 00:00:00'), 36.54),
 ('A', Timestamp('2000-09-12 00:00:00'), 35.41),
 ('A', Timestamp('2000-09-13 00:00:00'), 35.41),
 ('A', Timestamp('2000-09-14 00:00:00'), 35.89),
 ('A', Timestamp('2000-09-15 00:00:00'), 36.7)], 
      dtype=[('symbol', 'S1'), ('date', 'O'), ('close', '<f8')])
```

you can get the `dfPrice` by:

```
dfPrice = DataFrame(ra)
dfPrice.set_index(['symbol', 'date'], inplace=True)
```

what I want is to use the buy date and sell date and look up the minimum price in the interval I held the stock.

If I bought stock 'A' on 2000-09-07 and sold on 2000-09-14 (keeping it over the weekend without any price entries) I thought I could get the minimum price over that interval by using something like:

```
minPrice = dfPrice.min['A', '2000-09-07':'2000-09-14']
```

The answer is 35.41.

I have looked on Stack Overflow, but came up empty. What can I use to get what I want?

Comment: I edited your question. Please make an effort to capitalize your text: you'll find in the long run that it will benefit the reception of your question a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more straightforward way to do so, but I managed to get [advanced indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) to work using a tuple for your hierarchical indices:

```
>>> dfPrice[('A','2000-09-07'):('A','2000-09-14')]
                   close
symbol date             
 'A'   2000-09-07  39.84
       2000-09-08  38.15
       2000-09-11  36.54
       2000-09-12  35.41
       2000-09-13  35.41
       2000-09-14  35.89
>>> dfPrice[('A','2000-09-07'):('A','2000-09-14')].min()
close    35.41
dtype: float64
```

So for one you have to use advanced indexing in order to slice into your second level of indices, and you have to apply the `.min()` method to a sliced dataframe (rather than trying to put indices inside the call to `.min()`).

Comment: i tried this with the big dataframe (over 2,000,000 rows) a got an error message: KeyError: 'Key length (2) was greater than MultiIndex lexsort depth (0)' and i don't understand why - any help?

Comment: i tried this with the big dataframe (over 2,000,000 rows) a got an error message: KeyError: 'Key length (2) was greater than MultiIndex lexsort depth (0)'. experimenting i found it works with 100 rows and does not work with 1,000 rows. is there a work around for large dataframes?

Comment: @jeff97005 if it works for the smaller case, there might be something wrong with your large one. Are you sure the big dataframe properly has the same hierarchy? Can you compare the `dfPrice.index` for the small and the big case? I mean looking at `dfPrice.index.names`, `dfPrice.index.levels`, etc.

Comment: when i sorted the index everything worked.  i found the sort answer on stackoverflow. stackoverflow is a wonderful resource, thank you all for you generous support!

Comment: @jeff97005 I'm glad it worked out:) If you feel that my answer solved your question, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: i tried to vote up for you answer but i don't have enough reputation points to have it increase the count, sorry. i am a newbie. thanks for you input to a newbie.

Comment: @jeff97005 I know you don't:) But as an asker you can always mark an answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer: this will give reputation to the answerer, to you, and indicate that your question no longer needs an answer. Of course you should only do this if the specific answer really worked for you:)